# Equivalent of bwmorph(Image, 'thin', inf) in python

Tags: python, matlab

Is there any python function equivalent to `bwmorph(Image, 'thin', inf)` function of `matlab`?

Answer (score 0):

A number of binary morphological operations are present in the `skimage.morphology` module. You can find all of the documentation here: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html.

Some example operations:

- Binary closing
- Binary erosion
- Binary dilation
- Binary opening